# Implementing a ticket lock with atomics generates extra mov

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, locking

I wrote a naive implementation of a simple [ticket lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock#Implementation_of_Ticket_Lock). The locking part looks like:

```
struct ticket {
    uint16_t next_ticket;
    uint16_t now_serving;
};

void lock(ticket* tkt) {
    const uint16_t my_ticket =
        __sync_fetch_and_add(&tkt->next_ticket, 1); 
    while (tkt->now_serving != my_ticket) {
        _mm_pause();
        __asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory");
    }   
}
```

Then I realized that rather than using a gcc intrinsic, I can write this with `std::atomic`s:

```
struct atom_ticket {
    std::atomic<uint16_t> next_ticket;
    std::atomic<uint16_t> now_serving;
};

void lock(atom_ticket* tkt) {
    const uint16_t my_ticket =
        tkt->next_ticket.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (tkt->now_serving.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != my_ticket) {
        _mm_pause();
    }   
}
```

These generate *almost* identical assembly, but the latter generates an additional `movzwl` instruction. Why is there this extra `mov`? Is there a better, correct way to write `lock()`?

Assembly output with `-march=native -O3`:

```
 0000000000000000 <lock(ticket*)>:
    0:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    5:   66 f0 0f c1 07          lock xadd %ax,(%rdi)
    a:   66 39 47 02             cmp    %ax,0x2(%rdi)
    e:   74 08                   je     18 <lock(ticket*)+0x18>
   10:   f3 90                   pause  
   12:   66 39 47 02             cmp    %ax,0x2(%rdi)
   16:   75 f8                   jne    10 <lock(ticket*)+0x10>
   18:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
   1a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

```
 0000000000000020 <lock(atom_ticket*)>:
   20:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
   25:   66 f0 0f c1 17          lock xadd %dx,(%rdi)
   2a:   48 83 c7 02             add    $0x2,%rdi
   2e:   eb 02                   jmp    32 <lock(atom_ticket*)+0x12>
   30:   f3 90                   pause  
=> 32:   0f b7 07                movzwl (%rdi),%eax <== ???
   35:   66 39 c2                cmp    %ax,%dx
   38:   75 f6                   jne    30 <lock(atom_ticket*)+0x10>
   3a:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

Why not just `cmp (%rdi),%dx` directly?

Comment: To those researching this, `movzwl` reads 16 bits from the source and writes it to the bottom of the 32-bit destination register, zeroing the rest of the bits in the destination.

Comment: [Could this GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36873) report (not actually a bug) be related to it?  [fetch_add](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add) has `volatile` in definition of function?

Comment: @TonyTheLion There's no `volatile` here.

Comment: @Barry I was talking about the fact that `fetch_add` has `volatile` in its function definition.

Comment: @TonyTheLion There's a volatile-qualified overload, but the atomics in this example are not volatile.

Comment: Doesn't the first implementation miss an atomic load for the `now_serving` member variable? The disassembly for the first one looks like a potential infinite loop too. If it's only comparing data in the registers, how is a change from another thread going to propagate into the waiting thread?

Comment: @antiduh, Oh I get it. I also didn't notice the `02x(%rdi)` at cmp in 12 the first time I read the disassembly.

Comment: How do the codes using `uint32_t` instead of `uint16_t` compare?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I think you need to use `std::memory_order_acquire`, since you're acquiring a lock.  If you use `mo_relaxed`, you could potentially see stale data from before some of the stores that the previous lock-holder did.   [Jeff Preshing's blog is *excellent*, and he has a post on release/acquire semantics](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).

On x86, this can only happen if the compiler re-orders loads and stores, which `mo_relaxed` tells it it's allowed to.  An acquire load compiles the same as a relaxed load on x86, but without reordering.  *Every* x86 asm load is already an acquire.  On weakly-ordered architectures that need it, you'll get whatever instructions are needed for a load-acquire.  (And on x86, you'll just stop the compiler from reordering).

---

I put a version of the code [on godbolt](http://goo.gl/8fz7zR) to look at the asm with various compilers.

---

Well spotted, this does look like a gcc optimization failure, still present at least in 6.0 (checked with [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3OrpTSnSDI4brQp6), using a `main` that does `return execlp("objdump", "objdump", "-Mintel", "-d", argv[0], NULL);` to dump disassembler output of itself, including the functions we're interested in.

It looks like clang 3.7 does even worse with this.  It does a 16bit load, then zero-extends, then compares.

gcc treats atomic loads specially, and apparently fails to notice it can fold it into the compare.  Probably the optimization pass that could have done that happened while the atomic load was still represented differently from regular loads, or something.  I'm not a gcc hacker, so this is mostly guesswork.

I suspect either you have an old gcc (4.9.2 or older), or you're building on / for AMD, because your compiler [used `rep ret`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526361/what-does-rep-ret-mean) even with `-march=native`.  You should do something about that if you care about generating optimal code.  I've noticed gcc5 making better code than gcc 4.9 sometimes.  (not that it helps in this case, though :/)

---

I tried using uint32_t, with no luck.

The performance impact of doing the load and compare separately is probably irrelevant since this function is a busy-wait loop.

The fast path (unlocked case, where the loop condition is false on the first iteration) is still only one taken branch, and a ret.  However, in the std:atomic version, the fast path goes through the loop branch.  So instead of two separate branch-predictor entries (one for the fast path and one for the spin-loop), now spinning will probably cause a branch mispredict in the next unlocked case.  This is probably not an issue, and the new code does take one fewer branch-predictor entries.

IDK if jumping into the middle of a loop had any ill effects on the uop cache of Intel SnB-family microarchitectures.  It is something of a trace cache.  [Agner Fog's testing](http://agner.org/optimize/) found that the same piece of code can have multiple entries in the uop cache if it has multiple jump entry points.  This function is already somewhat uop-cache unfriendly, since it starts with a `mov r, imm / lock xadd`.  The lock xadd has to go in a uop cache line by itself, because it's microcoded (more than 4 uops.  9 in fact).  An unconditional jump always ends a uop cache line.  I'm not sure about a taken conditional branch, but I'd guess a taken jcc ends a cache line if it was predicted taken when it was decoded.  (e.g. branch predictor entry still good, but old uop cache entry evicted).

So the first version is potentially 3 uops cache lines for the fast-path: one `mov` (and if inlined, hopefully mostly full with previous instructions), one `lock xadd` alone, one macro-fused `cmp/je` to following code (if inlined.  If not, the jump targets the `ret`, which may end up as a 4th cache line for this 32byte code block, which isn't allowed.  So the non-inlined version of this may always have to get re-decoded every time?)

The std::atomic version is again one uop-cache line for the initial `mov imm` (and preceding instructions), then `lock xadd`, then `add / jmp`, then ... uh oh, 4th cache-line needed for the `movzx / compare-and-branch` uops.  So this version is more likely to have a decode bottleneck even when inlined.

Fortunately, the frontend can still gain some ground and get instructions queued up for the OOO core while running this code, because `lock xadd` is 9 uops.  That's enough to cover a cycle or two of fewer uops from the frontend, and a switch between decoding and uop-cache fetching.

The main problem here is just code-size, since you prob. want this inlined.  Speed-wise, the fast-path is only slightly worse, and the non-fast path is a spin-loop anyway so it doesn't matter.

The fast-path is 11 fused-domain uops for the old version (1 `mov imm`, 9 `lock xadd`, 1 `cmp/je` macro fused).  The `cmp/je` includes a micro-fused memory operand.

The fast-path is 41 fused-domain uops for the new version (1 `mov imm`, 9 `lock xadd`, 1 `add`, 1 `jmp`, 1 `movzx`, 1 `cmp/je` macro fused).

Using an `add` instead of just using an 8bit offset in the addressing mode of `movzx` is really shooting itself in the foot, IMO.  IDK if gcc thinks ahead far enough to make choices like that to have the loop branch target come out at a 16B boundary, or if that was just dumb luck.

---

Compiler-identification experiment on godbolt using the OP's code:

- gcc 4.8 and earlier: always use `rep ret` when it's a branch target, even with `-march=native -mtune=core2` (on a Haswell), or with just `-march=core2`.
- gcc 4.9: Uses `rep ret` with `-march=native` on Haswell, probably because Haswell is too new for it.  `-march=native -mtune=haswell` uses just `ret`, so it does know the name `haswell`.
- gcc 5.1 and later: uses `ret` with `-march=native` (on Haswell).  Still uses `rep ret` when `-march` isn't specified.

Answer (score 0):

In first one

```
12:   66 39 47 02             cmp    %ax,0x2(%rdi)
```

cmp is combined mov and cmp instruction (it is very likely to generate two instructions in microarchitecture instruction set)

The atomic variant is doing separate read for now_serving with

```
32:   0f b7 07                movzwl (%rdi),%eax
```

and then does same compare with

```
35:   66 39 c2                cmp    %ax,%dx
```

Comment: Actually, cmp can micro-fuse a memory operand on Intel CPUs, and still macro-fuse with a jcc into a single compare-and-branch uop with reg,mem operands.  AMD is the same, except it can't fuse cmp/jcc when the cmp uses a RIP-relative addressing mode.  Also, this unfortunately doesn't really answer the question of why, or how to get gcc not to do it.  (my answer doesn't either, since I didn't find a way)