# Deciphering x86 assembly function

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att, binary-bomb

I am currently working on phase 2 of the binary bomb assignment. I'm having trouble deciphering exactly what a certain function does when called. I've been stuck on it for days.

The function is:

```
0000000000400f2a <func2a>:
  400f2a:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
  400f2c:   74 1d                   je     400f4b <func2a+0x21>
  400f2e:   b9 cd cc cc cc          mov    $0xcccccccd,%ecx
  400f33:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  400f35:   f7 e1                   mul    %ecx
  400f37:   c1 ea 03                shr    $0x3,%edx
  400f3a:   8d 04 92                lea    (%rdx,%rdx,4),%eax
  400f3d:   01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax
  400f3f:   29 c7                   sub    %eax,%edi
  400f41:   83 04 be 01             addl   $0x1,(%rsi,%rdi,4)
  400f45:   89 d7                   mov    %edx,%edi
  400f47:   85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
  400f49:   75 e8                   jne    400f33 <func2a+0x9>
  400f4b:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

It gets called in the larger function "phase_2":

```
0000000000400f4d <phase_2>: 
  400f4d:   53                      push   %rbx
  400f4e:   48 83 ec 60             sub    $0x60,%rsp
  400f52:   48 c7 44 24 30 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x30(%rsp)
  400f59:   00 00 
  400f5b:   48 c7 44 24 38 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x38(%rsp)
  400f62:   00 00 
  400f64:   48 c7 44 24 40 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x40(%rsp)
  400f6b:   00 00 
  400f6d:   48 c7 44 24 48 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x48(%rsp)
  400f74:   00 00 
  400f76:   48 c7 44 24 50 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x50(%rsp)
  400f7d:   00 00 
  400f7f:   48 c7 04 24 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,(%rsp)
  400f86:   00 
  400f87:   48 c7 44 24 08 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x8(%rsp)
  400f8e:   00 00 
  400f90:   48 c7 44 24 10 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x10(%rsp)
  400f97:   00 00 
  400f99:   48 c7 44 24 18 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x18(%rsp)
  400fa0:   00 00 
  400fa2:   48 c7 44 24 20 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x20(%rsp)
  400fa9:   00 00 
  400fab:   48 8d 4c 24 58          lea    0x58(%rsp),%rcx
  400fb0:   48 8d 54 24 5c          lea    0x5c(%rsp),%rdx
  400fb5:   be 9e 26 40 00          mov    $0x40269e,%esi
  400fba:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400fbf:   e8 6c fc ff ff          callq  400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
  400fc4:   83 f8 02                cmp    $0x2,%eax
  400fc7:   74 05                   je     400fce <phase_2+0x81>
  400fc9:   e8 c1 06 00 00          callq  40168f <explode_bomb>
  400fce:   83 7c 24 5c 64          cmpl   $0x64,0x5c(%rsp)
  400fd3:   76 07                   jbe    400fdc <phase_2+0x8f>
  400fd5:   83 7c 24 58 64          cmpl   $0x64,0x58(%rsp)
  400fda:   77 05                   ja     400fe1 <phase_2+0x94>
  400fdc:   e8 ae 06 00 00          callq  40168f <explode_bomb>
  400fe1:   48 8d 74 24 30          lea    0x30(%rsp),%rsi
  400fe6:   8b 7c 24 5c             mov    0x5c(%rsp),%edi
  400fea:   e8 3b ff ff ff          callq  400f2a <func2a>
  400fef:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  400ff2:   8b 7c 24 58             mov    0x58(%rsp),%edi
  400ff6:   e8 2f ff ff ff          callq  400f2a <func2a>
  400ffb:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
  401000:   8b 04 1c                mov    (%rsp,%rbx,1),%eax
  401003:   39 44 1c 30             cmp    %eax,0x30(%rsp,%rbx,1)
  401007:   74 05                   je     40100e <phase_2+0xc1>
  401009:   e8 81 06 00 00          callq  40168f <explode_bomb>
  40100e:   48 83 c3 04             add    $0x4,%rbx
  401012:   48 83 fb 28             cmp    $0x28,%rbx
  401016:   75 e8                   jne    401000 <phase_2+0xb3>
  401018:   48 83 c4 60             add    $0x60,%rsp
  40101c:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  40101d:   c3                      retq
```

I completely understand what phase_2 is doing, I just don't understand what func2a is doing and how it affects the values at 0x30(%rsp) and so on. Because of this I always get to the comparison statement at 0x401003, and the bomb eventually explodes there.

My problem is I don't understand how the input (phase solution) is affecting the values at 0x30(%rsp) via func2a.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
  400f2a:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
  400f2c:   74 1d                   je     400f4b <func2a+0x21>
```

This is just an early exit for when `edi` is zero (`je` is the same as `jz`).

```
  400f2e:   b9 cd cc cc cc          mov    $0xcccccccd,%ecx
  400f33:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  400f35:   f7 e1                   mul    %ecx
  400f37:   c1 ea 03                shr    $0x3,%edx
```

This is a classic optimization trick; it is the integer arithmetic equivalent of dividing by multiplying by the inverse (see [here for details](http://www.flounder.com/multiplicative_inverse.htm)); in practice, here it's the same as saying `edx = edi / 10`;

```
  400f3a:   8d 04 92                lea    (%rdx,%rdx,4),%eax
  400f3d:   01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax
```

Here it is exploiting `lea` to perform arithmetic (and it's way clearer in Intel syntax, where it is `lea eax,[rdx+rdx*4]` => `eax = edx*5`), then sums the result with itself. It all boils down to `eax = edx*10`.

```
  400f3f:   29 c7                   sub    %eax,%edi
```

Then, subtract it back to `edi`.

---

So, all in all this is a complicated (but fast) way to compute the last decimal digit of `edi`; what we have until now is something like:

```
void func2a(unsigned edi) {
    if(edi==0) return;
label1:
    edx=edi/10;
    edi%=10;
    // ...
}
```

(`label1:` is there because `400f33` is a jump target later)

---

Going on:

```
  400f41:   83 04 be 01             addl   $0x1,(%rsi,%rdi,4)
```

Again, this is way clearer to me in Intel syntax - `add dword [rsi+rdi*4],byte +0x1`. It is a regular increment into an array of 32-bit `int` (`rdi` is multiplied by 4); so, we can imagine that `rsi` points to an array of integers, indexed with the just-calculated last digit of `edi`.

```
void func2a(unsigned edi, int rsi[]) {
    if(edi==0) return;
label1:
    edx=edi/10;
    edi%=10;
    rsi[edi]++;
}
```

Then:

```
  400f45:   89 d7                   mov    %edx,%edi
  400f47:   85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
  400f49:   75 e8                   jne    400f33 <func2a+0x9>
```

Move the result of the division we calculated above to `edi`, and loop if it's different from zero.

```
  400f4b:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

Return (using [an unusual encoding of the instruction that is optimal for certain AMD processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526361/what-does-rep-ret-mean)).

---

So, by rewriting the jumps with a `while` loop and giving some meaningful names...

```
// number is edi, digits_count is rsi, as per regular
// x64 SystemV calling convention
void count_digits(unsigned number, int digits_count[]) {
    while(number) {
        digits_count[number%10]++;
        number/=10;
    }
}
```

I.e., this is a function that, given an integer, counts the occurrences of the single decimal digits, by incrementing the corresponding buckets in the `digits_count` array.

---

Fun fact: if we give the C code above to `gcc` (almost any recent version at `-O1`) [we obtain back exactly the assembly you provided](https://godbolt.org/g/rZSzIn).

Comment: "if we give the C code above to gcc we obtain back exactly the assembly you provided." -> perfect reverse engineering. Great answer!