# Writing a C function from given x86 assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer this mystery function. 
This function returns an integer and takes a struct node as an argument

```
#include "mystery.h"
int mystery(struct e4_struct *s){}
```

The header file is a simple struct declaration

```
struct my_struct {
    int a;
    int b; 
};
```

The assembly I'm trying to reverse engineer is

```
400596:    8b 07                    mov    (%rdi),%eax
400598:    8d 04 40                 lea    (%rax,%rax,2),%eax
40059b:    89 07                    mov    %eax,(%rdi)
40059d:    83 47 04 07              addl   $0x7,0x4(%rdi)
4005a1:    c3                       retq
```

So far I think the function is like:

```
int mystery(struct m_struct *s){
    int i = s->a;
    i = 3*i;
    int j = s->b;
    j += 7;
    return i;
}
```

But this isn't correct. I don't understand what `mov  %eax,(%rdi)`does exactly and what the function returns in the end because its supposed to return and integer.

Comment: Obviously `j += 7` has no effect so it can't be right. The `addl` operates on the content of memory directly, so that's `s->b += 7` and you have no `j` at all. Also, you forgot the `mov %eax, (%rdi)`.

Comment: s->a = s->a * 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that *RDI* is the pointer to the beginning of the structure (first parameter of function) the following line is getting the value of `s->a`and placing it in a temporary register *EAX*.

```
mov    (%rdi),%eax
```

Reasonably that might be `int x = s->a`. This line:

```
lea    (%rax,%rax,2),%eax
```

Is the same as multiplying the temp value by 3 since RAX+RAX*2=3*RAX (thus s->a * 3). So the first two lines of assembly could be represented as:

```
int x = s->a * 3;
```

The line `mov %eax,(%rdi)` would be taking the temporary value `x` and storing it back to s->a so that could be represented as:

```
s->a = x;
```

The line `addl $0x7,0x4(%rdi)` is adding 7 to the value at 4(RDI). 4(RDI) is the address of s->b. This line could be represented as `s->b += 7;`.

So what is being returned as a value? Since nothing else is done with *EAX* after the code analyzed above, *EAX* is is still the value it had earlier when we did `x = s->a * 3;`. This means that the function is returning the temporary value `x`.

The code then would look like this:

```
int mystery(struct my_struct *s)
{
    int x = s->a * 3;
    s->a = x;
    s->b += 7;
    return x;    
}
```

If you compile this code with GCC 4.9.x on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'struct+my_struct+%7B%0A++++int+a%3B%0A++++int+b%3B+%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+mystery(struct+my_struct+*s)%0A%7B%0A++++int+x+%3D+s-%3Ea+*+3%3B%0A++++s-%3Ea+%3D+x%3B%0A++++s-%3Eb+%2B%3D+7%3B%0A++++return+x%3B++++%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g494,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O1',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.9.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) with `-O1` optimization level we get this generated assembly:

```
mystery:
        movl    (%rdi), %eax
        leal    (%rax,%rax,2), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%rdi)
        addl    $7, 4(%rdi)
        ret
```

Different compilers with different optimizations levels will produce different assembly that will all do the same thing. GCC 4.9.x just so happens to produce the **exact** assembly code we originally reverse engineered.

---

Note: I guessed on the version of compiler and optimization level because of a recent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344011/trying-to-reverse-engineer-a-function) with a different `mystery` function where I had found GCC 4.9.x with optimization level `-O1` generated the exact code I was looking for. It seems whoever generated the assembly files for these *mystery* exercises was using such settings and similar compiler.