# how to use lzcnt with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I'm looking at some assembly code and I'm seeing tzcntl. A search for that instruction redirects to lzcnt. Are these the same instructions? Is it possible to use lzcnt with gcc?

I've seen this example:
[Intrinsic __lzcnt64 returns different values with different compile options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678547/intrinsic-lzcnt64-returns-different-values-with-different-compile-options)

Although I'm confused about whether or not I need to use __lzcnt64 or if there is a 32 bit version.

So in summary:

1. What's the difference between tzcntl and lzcnt, if any?
2. How to properly use lzcnt with gcc (code, includes, and compiling)
3. Can I select a 32 bit or 64 bit version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tzcnt` counts *trailing* zeros, while `lzcnt` counts *leading* zeros.

The [x86 compiler built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html) provide access to `lzcnt` instructions for various register widths:

```
unsigned short __builtin_ia32_lzcnt_u16(unsigned short);
unsigned int __builtin_ia32_lzcnt_u32(unsigned int);
unsigned long long __builtin_ia32_lzcnt_u64 (unsigned long long);
```

But these are only available with `-mlzcnt` and will give wrong results if the CPU doesn't support executing `rep bsr` as `lzcnt`.

But you can use the generic built-ins for bit counting. See [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fclzll):

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_clzll (unsigned long long)`
>
> > Similar to `__builtin_clz`, except the argument type is `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I don't think we should advertise `__builtin_ia32_*` too much, they are implementation details for intrinsics like `__lzcnt32` (include `x86intrin.h`). Indeed the generic builtins are better, unless you require a specific behavior when called on `0`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse   As linked in the answer I was able to find something like __builtin_ia32_lzcnt_u32. From the other SO question linked in mine above, I saw __lzcnt64. I probably should have tried __lzcnt32 to see if that worked. How would I know about __lzcnt32 (and __lzcnt64) in general?

Comment: `__lzcnt32` are documented in the Intel manuals, but the Intel intrinsics are not really useful with GCC because of the compiler flags required for them.

Comment: What do you mean about the required compiler flags? You can put `__attribute__((target("lzcnt")))` on the function directly using the intrinsic if you don't want to pass it on the command line. If you want `__builtin_clz` to expand to this instruction, you'll need something similar.

Comment: On older compiler versions, the Intel intrinsic headers [do not provide definitions if the `-m` flags are missing](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-04/msg00740.html).

Comment: Yeah, but that's been fixed a while ago, I don't think that's a reason to discourage use in new code.